# How to send data received from api to another ? react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, sequelize.js

I'm working in an application with React in frontend and nodejs/express/sequelize in backend
i have a page that shows to client to buy tickets for an event for different person
i send data to the backend when he submit the form like this:

**frontendUrl: *website/booking/event_id* 

apiUrl: *api/booking* [POST]**

**req.body: { event_id, spectators[]: { ticket_id, price, first_name, last_name, gender, birthday }**
spectator is an array contains object for diffrent person want to book ticket for them

I have an api for the e-paiment i must work with it to complete the process of buying the ticket.

in the documention 
1-first i need to call tha api epayment like this
**apiUrlEpaiment: api-e-paiment/?price&orderNumber&usernameApi&passwordApi&returnUrl**

i have to create the orderNumber by me as the doc said.
returnUrl: i must to put the redirect url when the process finished
in my case i put: **website/checkout**

then response of the api {errCode, formUrl}

i have to return the response to frontendUrl: website/booking/event_id then check if errCode === 0 thats mean its ok and i have to redirect user to formUrl ( a gateway from the api e-paiment where the client can buy with his bank card )

the formUrl redirect the client to other website like this epaimentbank/orderNumber ( he has 10 minutes to complete or the process will expire )
2-
to check if payment succes i have to call
apiEpaimentUrl: api-e-paiment/orderNumber
**forendtUrl:website/checkou?orderNumber**

here i receive if payment succeeded or failed

my problem is when payment succeeded i want to sotre spectator in my DB on table Booking
but i didnt know how to get the data because i lost the data when the api redirect the client to gateway payment

i think to make a temporary table tmp_booking i sotre on it the information when i call **apiUrl: api/booking [POST]**

and i make a cron-job schedule every 10 minutes and delete all rows from tmp_boking with this uery

Delete from tmp_booking WHERE createdAt < now() - interval 10 minute;

but i feel like its a bad idea

how i can do it ?

thnaks

Comment: Using a temporary table is actually a good idea if the payment process can take longer to complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715620/delay-order-requests-in-nodejs-application-for-some-specific-duration

Comment: I think it depends that you want to do this job in front or back end. The temp table is a back end solution. Also you can do this by redux. we can think of the whole transaction as a flow. we can assign a unique id to the flow and in each stage of the transaction the flow id will be there.  And then update the data in redux based on the response status.

Comment: you can use thunk or saga to implement the chaining api requests

Comment: @Jerry here the chaining is not a solution because we're working with 2 different pages and the user can leave the page or the browser and we lost the data

Comment: @Jslover what is the structure of your web app? redux shares data across the whole web app. that means you can access redux data from any page in your app. and if you can make the process and your web structure more clear that would help